# Decrypting RSA with the key

Tags: rsa

I have a

- 1024-bits modulus n,
- the key d which is 1022 bit long,
- public exponent 65537,
- two factor p and q,
- and the ciphertext y 1023 bits which is all in numbers.

How can we perform decryption and work out the plaintext? I have tried **CrypTool**, tried entering the key d, two factor p and q, but it always give me an error saying

`Output block size = 127 is too small must be 128`

Comment: The output size is the (minimum) size of the modulus in bytes. So you could enter 128 and then simply ignore the leftmost bit.

Answer (score 1):

Being that you have all of the necessary ingredients (p, q, n, d, and e) as integers, you can use [rsatool](https://github.com/ius/rsatool) to create a .pem file containing the private key in PEM format.

Then, you can use `openssl rsautil -decrypt` to decrypt the ciphertext, using the private key in PEM format.  See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-rsautl.html for more info.

Note that openssl operates on raw bytes.  You say that you have `ciphertext y 1023 bits which is all in numbers`, so you may need to convert these number to bytes for openssl to operate on.